# AMD GPU not recognised with OpenCL - Ubuntu

Tags: qt, opencl, gpu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to recognize my AMD FirePro W5100 GPU with OpenCl on Ubuntu 16.04.
I'm using:

- AMD APP SDK 3.0 https://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/
- GPU latest driver for Ubuntu 16.04 http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/workstation?os=Linux%20x86_64#pro-driver

Running `clinfo` seems like both the AMD platform and device are recognized and it looks like this:

```html
Number of platforms:     1
  Platform Profile:     FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:     OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2482.3)
  Platform Name:     AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:     cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 


  Platform Name:     AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:     1
  Device Type:      CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Vendor ID:      1002h
  Board name:      AMD FirePro W5100
  Device Topology:     PCI[ B#5, D#0, F#0 ]
  Max compute units:     12
  Max work items dimensions:    3
    Max work items[0]:     256
    Max work items[1]:     256
    Max work items[2]:     256
  Max work group size:     256
  Preferred vector width char:    4
  Preferred vector width short:    2
  Preferred vector width int:    1
  Preferred vector width long:    1
  Preferred vector width float:    1
  Preferred vector width double:   1
  Native vector width char:    4
  Native vector width short:    2
  Native vector width int:    1
  Native vector width long:    1
  Native vector width float:    1
  Native vector width double:    1
  Max clock frequency:     930Mhz
  Address bits:      64
  Max memory allocation:    2970166886
  Image support:     Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:   128
  Max number of images write arguments:   8
  Max image 2D width:     16384
  Max image 2D height:     16384
  Max image 3D width:     2048
  Max image 3D height:     2048
  Max image 3D depth:     2048
  Max samplers within kernel:    16
  Max size of kernel argument:    1024
  Alignment (bits) of base address:   2048
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:  128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:      No
    Quiet NaNs:      Yes
    Round to nearest even:    Yes
    Round to zero:     Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:    Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:   Yes
  Cache type:      Read/Write
  Cache line size:     64
  Cache size:      16384
  Global memory size:     3551735808
  Constant buffer size:     2970166886
  Max number of constant args:    8
  Local memory type:     Scratchpad
  Local memory size:     32768
  Max pipe arguments:     0
  Max pipe active reservations:    0
  Max pipe packet size:     0
  Max global variable size:    0
  Max global variable preferred total size:  0
  Max read/write image args:    0
  Max on device events:     0
  Queue on device max size:    0
  Max on device queues:     0
  Queue on device preferred size:   0
  SVM capabilities:     
    Coarse grain buffer:    No
    Fine grain buffer:     No
    Fine grain system:     No
    Atomics:      No
  Preferred platform atomic alignment:   0
  Preferred global atomic alignment:   0
  Preferred local atomic alignment:   0
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:  64
  Error correction support:    0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:   0
  Profiling timer resolution:    1
  Device endianess:     Little
  Available:      Yes
  Compiler available:     Yes
  Execution capabilities:     
    Execute OpenCL kernels:    Yes
    Execute native function:    No
  Queue on Host properties:     
    Out-of-Order:     No
    Profiling :      Yes
  Queue on Device properties:     
    Out-of-Order:     No
    Profiling :      No
  Platform ID:      0x7f77f5366098
  Name:       Bonaire
  Vendor:      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device OpenCL C version:    OpenCL C 1.2 
  Driver version:     2482.3
  Profile:      FULL_PROFILE
  Version:      OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2482.3)
  Extensions:      cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_spir cl_khr_gl_event
```

However, when I run the OpenCL code, it can identify the AMD platform but not the AMD device/GPU:

```
vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
cout << "Platforms found: " << platforms.size() << endl;

for(int j = 0; j < platforms.size(); j++){
    cout << "\nPlatform #" << j+1 << endl;
    cout << "Platform vendor: " << platforms[j].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR>() << endl;
    vector<cl::Device> devices;
    platforms[j].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);

    for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Device " << i << " - vendor = " << devices[i].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>() << " - Version = " << devices[i].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VERSION>() << endl;
    }

}
```

I get:

```
Platforms found: 1

Platform #1
Platform vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Device 0 - vendor = GenuineIntel - Version = OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1800.8)
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

**UPDATE**:
Apparently the problem exists only if I run my project with either QT or NetBeans. Eclipse recognizes the GPU and works. I can't find a valid reason and I'd prefer working on Qt. Ideas?

Comment: To clarify - your `clinfo` doesn't show the CPU device?

Comment: @HEKTO I don't really mind about the CPU. I need to use my GPU that is recognized and listed in clinfo but not when running my code with Qt

Comment: I know... the `clinfo` usually shows CPU as well. If it doesn't then it's bad symptom. As for your program - it shows the CPU only, you can verify that with `getInfo<CL_DEVICE_TYPE>()`

Comment: As for running your programs from IDE - I don't know about Qt, but NetBeans won't import all your environment variables, for example - `OCL_ICD_VENDORS`

Comment: I don't understand how this can influence my problem to be honest. And yes, the device listed by my program is of course the CPU. That's the reason why I posted it, to emphasize the fact that it's detecting the CPU but not the GPU. The GPU is detected using other IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) though. The environment variables are a good point. I will investigate more on that and I'll let you know, thanks!

Comment: The `clinfo` has been installed from the AMD SDK, right? And this SDK wasn't updated by AMD for a long time - that might affect you also